# How to open port 555 on Linux / Debian

Tags: linux, debian, port

I want that phpmyadmin to work at mysite.com:555 (555 port)

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration
<VirtualHost *:555>
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But mysite.com:555 is not works....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since that appears to be an Apache config I suspect you also need to add a `Listen` directive to the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` (for Debian).

It should be `Listen 555`.

Comment: +1. Note you'll need an *additional* `Listen` line as well as the `Listen 80` that's likely already there.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `Listen 555` in your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file